# extract specific part of text from cell

Tags: excel

I have an excel file where cells have the following content:

```
a:4:{s:8:"linkedin";s:37:"linkedin.com/in/username";s:7:"twitter";s:33:"twitter.com/username";s:7:"website";s:25:"website.com";s:6:"google";s:47:"plus.google.com/+username";}
```

So one cell has all of the above text in it. There are thousands of cells that all have their own unique urls within this text. So for example **twitter.com/username** shows their actual username instead.

I want to create a formula with which i can extract only the twitter url from a particular cell. So that i get a clean list of only twitter urls.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the following formula (this assumes that the text is in Cell A1; adjust that to suit)

```
=MID(A1,FIND("twitter.com",A1),FIND(";",A1,FIND("twitter.com",A1))-FIND("twitter.com",A1)-1)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That's perfect! Even better, would you know how it could show only the twitter username instead of the entire url?

Comment: I just added a value of 12 (number of characters in twitter.com/) to the FIND formula: `=MID(A1,FIND("twitter.com",A1)+12,FIND(";",A1,FIND("twitter.com",A1))-FIND("twitter.com",A1)-13)'